# Find index of selected menu option using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select menu.  I wish to obtain the index of the currently selected option.  Upon initial page load, it would be zero unless `selected="selected"` is included in the HTML.  If later it was changed, the index would indicate the currently selected option.  The following works on my current browser, but I would like confirmation whether this is the best cross-browser solution.

```
var i=$('#mySelectID').prop("selectedIndex");
```

Note.  While I show `$('#mySelectID')`, my example actually loops over several elements  so it is really `$(this)`, but I don't think that makes any difference.

Comment: `var i = getElementById('mySelectID').selectedIndex`

Comment: yes it should work....  why not simply test it

Comment: Yes, I did test it and it works great on my browser.  Wasn't sure about older browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may also use [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method:

```
var i = $("#mySelectID :selected").index();
```

This is cross browser and gives a result on page load and if you have no options selected.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mZ9Dc/

Comment: As indicated at the bottom of my  post, I really don't have an id of the element, but am looping over $(this).  Thanks

Comment: @user1032531 No problem with that: `var i = $(this).children(":selected").index();`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var selectedIndex = $('#mySelectID :selected').index();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use

```
var i=$('#mySelectID :selected').val();  //if you have given the values
```

or

```
var i=$('#mySelectID :selected').text(); //if you have used the text
```